# Is it a good idea to use WAMP server as a web server?

Tags: webserver, windows-server-2008, wampserver, vds

I have bought a VDS (Virtual Dedicated Server) that Windows Server 2008 is installed on it. I needed to use server because I have developed a C# console application that can read data by TCP socket and write them in the MySQL database.
Now I need to start a website on this server. I think WAMP server is so easy for me.
Maybe in future a lot of people visit my website.
Is it a good idea to use WAMP server as a web server?

Answer (score 3):

In principal there is nothing wrong with using WAMPServer as a LIVE webserver.

**However, not the out of the box version**.

Out of the box WAMPServer and XAMPP for that matter expect to be used as a single seat developer tool and while that is great for a click and go solution to get a developer up and running on Apache/MySQL and PHP in a few minutes **it is not secure enough** to be considered as a LIVE web facing webserver.

Now if you have the knowledge and experience to create an user account on Windows Server that has access to only what Apache needs to do its work, and can get Apache to run in that account instead of its default account (which has way to many privilages for a live server) and are prepared to explore all the Apache security features/modules that would be required for a web facing server then it is possible. However this is not a trivial task, and any mistakes or ommissions will leave your server open to the simplest of hacks.

In short, unless you really know what you are doing with Windows Server and Apache, you would be far better to pay for a professionally configured and managed web server environment.

Comment: I would like to know Why? " it is not secure enough "